# Views shows uploaded paperclip images as /original/missing.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have Product model which are items in the e-commerce store and is configured with paperclip to i can upload images for the product model.

When i add the image for the product, the image appears in /system/image/../.../.../thumbs and original but when i do

```
 <% for product in @products %>
    <%= link_to product.image.url(:original)  %>

  <% end %>
```

it appears broken links (/system/image/missing.png) when i browse the page. Similar to doing a group of thumbnails - i am trying to achieve to get all the product images out like a thumbnail. (eg. photo gallery)

Other code include model are below:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :image

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "238x238>",
                                         :thumb => "100x100>" }

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image

end
```

Controller:

```
  def index
   @products = Product.all
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the Paperclip know about the location of where to store/read the attachments.

Add the following options to `has_attached_file`:

```
:url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: It is still the same, the URL shows /system/images/missing.png. Is it something wrong with my paperclip? It is version 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer is someone stumbles upon this.

You will need to generate the paperclip Migration.

rails g paperclip Model attachment (for example: rails g paperclip User avatar) - the "attachment" is the one you defined in "has_attached_file".

Secondly, you need to add:

```
attr_accessible :image, :image_file_name, :image_content_type
```

i did that and viola! it worked!